# Solving $(x-y)u_x+u_y=x,~~~u(x,0)=x^2$ by the method of characteristics.

Tags: partial-differential-equations, characteristics

Q. Solve $$(x-y)u_x+u_y=x,~~~u(x,0)=x^2$$ by the method of characteristics.

I am getting the general solution from Lagrange-Charpit equations as $u=x+\frac{y^2}{2}+C$, where $C$ is an arbitrary constant. But it seems to be not coorporate with initial curve. How can I deal with this?

Comment: Can you write down the Lagrange-Charpit equations which you got? (That is, before solving them)

Comment: $\frac{dx}{x-y}=\frac{dy}{1}=\frac{du}{x}$

Comment: Using first equality, I am getting $x+y=C$

Comment: $\frac{dx}{dy} = x-y$ does not give $x+y = C$, it gives $x = Ce^y+y+1$.

Comment: ya...you are correct, I made wrong

Comment: Its $x=Ce^y-y+1$, right?

Comment: I just took it from Wolfram, so check your working once, then I'll go through it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$(x-y)u_x+u_y=x$$
$$\frac{dx}{x-y}=\frac{dy}{1}=\frac{du}{x}$$
First characteristic equation from solving $\frac{dx}{x-y}=\frac{dy}{1}$ :
$$(x-y-1)e^{-y}=c_1$$
$x=c_1e^y+y+1$

Second characteristic equation from solving $\frac{dy}{1}=\frac{du}{x}=\frac{du}{c_1e^y+y+1}\quad\implies\quad\frac{du}{dy}=c_1e^y+y+1$ :
$$u-\frac{y^2}{2}-y-c_1e^y=c_2$$
$$u-\frac{y^2}{2}-y-((x-y-1)e^{-y})e^y=c_2$$
$$u-\frac{y^2}{2}-x+1=c_2$$
The general solution of the PDE expressed on the form of implicit equation $c_2=F(c_1)$ with arbitrary function $F$ is :
$$u-\frac{y^2}{2}-x+1=F\big((x-y-1)e^{-y} \big)$$
Explicitly the general solution of the PDE is :
$$\boxed{u(x,y)=\frac{y^2}{2}+x-1+F\big((x-y-1)e^{-y} \big)}$$
Condition :
$$u(x,0)=x^2=\frac{0^2}{2}+x-1+F\big((x-0-1)e^{-0} \big)$$
$$x^2-x+1=F(x-1)$$
Let $X=x-1\quad;\quad x=X+1$
$$(X+1)^2-(X+1)+1=F(X)$$
$$F(X)=X^2+X+1$$
Now the function $F$ is known. We put it into the above general solution where $X=(x-y-1)e^{-y}$ .
$$u(x,y)=\frac{y^2}{2}+x-1+\big((x-y-1)e^{-y}\big)^2+\big((x-y-1)e^{-y}\big)+1$$
The particular solution of the PDE which satisfies the specified condition is :
$$\boxed{u(x,y)=\frac{y^2}{2}+x+(x-y-1)^2e^{-2y}+(x-y-1)e^{-y}}$$